# http POST invoke-WebRequest Parameters adding text

Tags: powershell, http, batch-file, httpwebrequest, invoke-command

I can get plain text to show up, I can get a variable first and then text to show- however, I am trying to get for example, a label, then the variable:

```
Computer Name: $env:computername
```

Returns errors.

The Batch Command I am using is:

```js
powershell -Command "& {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://script.google.com/macros/s//exec -Method POST -Body text="$env:computername, $env:os, $env:username, $env:thisip"}"
```

I would like to simply label each variable within the Command, such as:

```js
powershell -Command "& {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://script.google.com/macros/s//exec -Method POST -Body text="ComputerName: $env:computername, OS: $env:os, UserName: $env:username, IP: $env:thisip"}"
```

However I continue to get errors- regarding positional parameters.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your problem is related to single quotes within single quotes.  You need to double-quote the inner single quotes or the string is being interpreted as being terminated mid-string.

Comment: duh. Thanks for the help! So easy to miss these things! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

@thepip3r correctly pointed out:

> Looks like your problem is related to single quotes within single
>   quotes. You need to double-quote the inner single quotes or the string
>   is being interpreted as being terminated mid-string.

i changed to below and it worked:

```js
powershell -Command "& {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://script.google.com/macros/s//exec -Method POST -Body text='ComputerName: $env:computername, OS: $env:os, UserName: $env:username, IP: $env:thisip'}"
```